# Bind variables only allowed in apex code

Tags: apex, soql

I have two objects with Master-Detail relationship between them where Phase is Master Object and Phase Entity is Child object.I am trying to compare the data(field values) in eclipse.But I am getting an error **Bind variables only allowed in apex code**.

How to compare data(field values) between master and child objects?

```
Select e.Fund__c, e.Phase__r.Fund__c, e.Phase__c From  Phase_Entity__c e where e.Phase__r.Fund__c != e.Fund__c
```

Comment: Related: [Query to Compare Two Date Fields](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/40943/query-to-compare-two-date-fields) and [Field to field comparison in WHERE clause of SOQL](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000187460&language=en_US)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SOQL won't let you compare fields within a query. You'll need to make a checkbox formula field on Phase_Entity__c.