# Query to Compare Two Date Fields

Tags: soql

```
SELECT count() FROM Case where  lastmodifieddate > Createddate
```

basically i am trying to compare the two date time fields, but i am getting below error in workbench.

> MALFORMED_QUERY:  Case where lastmodifieddate > Createddate
>
> ^ ERROR
>   at Row:1:Column:51 Bind variables only allowed in Apex code

Answer (score 15):

The way you are trying to do this isn't possible. [Salesforce docs](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000187460&language=en_US):

> **Field to field comparison in WHERE clause of SOQL**
>
> **Description**
>
> I want to execute a query by comparing two fields of the same object in WHERE clause, but I am not able to use a field in
>   the right hand side of a condition in a WHERE clause:
>
> ```
> List<user> users = [SELECT Id,name FROM User WHERE (FirstName != Lastname)];
> ```
>
> The above query returns: "System.QueryException: unexpected token:
>   'Lastname' "
>
> **Resolution**
>
> Salesforce doesn't allow direct field to field comparison in SOQL query.
>
> To achieve this you may create a formula field that will compare
>   fields and return a value (like true or false) which you may use in a
>   WHERE clause.
>
> So for the above query, you could create a formula field on User
>   object with return type Text e.g. NameCompare, with the formula
>   IF(User.FirstName != User.LastName, 'true', 'false')
>
> Now our query will be:
>
> ```
> List<User> Users = [SELECT id, name FROM User where NameCompare= 'true'];
> ```
>
> Following idea has been posted on ideaexchange portal for allowing
>   field-to-field comparison in SOQL:
>
> https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrHAAA0

In your specific scenario, you will want to create a [formula field](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=tips_for_using_date_datetime_formula_fields.htm&language=en_US) of type Checkbox like:

```
LastModifiedDate >  CreatedDate
```

Then rewrite your query with your WHERE clause like:

```
SELECT count() FROM Case where Last_Modified_Greater_Than_Created__c = true
```

Comment: Now that checkbox formula fields are available, is there any reason not to use those instead of 'true' and 'false' strings?

Comment: Not that I know of to be honest @KeithC. I didn't even think about that. Using a checkbox would be a better idea.

Comment: Updated the answer to use a checkbox formula field instead of Text.

Comment: You should mention that using formulas like this cause full table scans, which will result in aborted queries if they're too large.